# Mongoose and Mongodb Returns All but Coordinates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I'm trying to retrieve a full document, and the query returns everything I need except the coordinates in my document.

Here's an example document in my database:

**Sample Document**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5733e359dcba0f6d5aa88cee"
    },
    "name": "Starcups",
    "address": "906 Buford Hwy, Cumming, GA 30041",
    "rating": 3,
    "facilities": [
        "Hot drinks",
        "Food",
        "Premium wifi"
    ],
    "coords": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -84.132809,
            34.180035
        ]
    },
    "openingTimes": [
        {
            "days": "Monday - Friday",
            "opening": "7:00am",
            "closing": "7:00pm",
            "closed": false
        },
        {
            "days": "Saturday",
            "opening": "8:00am",
            "closing": "5:00pm",
            "closed": false
        },
        {
            "days": "Sunday",
            "closed": true
        }
    ],
    "reviews": [
        {
            "author": "Kenny Hall",
            "rating": 5,
            "timestamp": "13 April 2016",
            "reviewText": "What a great place. I can't say enough good things about it."
        },
        {
            "author": "Charlie Chaplin",
            "rating": 3,
            "timestamp": "16 June 2015",
            "reviewText": "It was okay. Coffee wasn't great, but the wifi was fast."
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, there's a field in the document called `coords`. The entire document is returned except this field.

Here's my controller logic:

**Controller Logic**

```
/* GET a location by the id */
module.exports.locationsReadOne = function(req, res) {
    if (req.params && req.params.locationid) {
        Loc.findById(req.params.locationid).exec(function(err, location) {
            console.log(location);
            if (!location) {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 404, { "message" : "locationid not found" });
                return;
            } else if (err) {
                sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err);
                return;
            }
            sendJsonResponse(res, 200, location);
        });
    } else {
        sendJsonResponse(res, 404, { "message" : "No locationid in request"});
    }
};
```

Any idea why it's not returning the `coords` part? I'll include my schema in case that matters:

**Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    reviewText: String,
    createdOn: {
        type: Date,
        "default": Date.now
    }
});

var openingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    days: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    opening: String,
    closing: String,
    closed: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    }
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: String,
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        "default": 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 5
    },
    facilities: [String],
    // Always store coordinates longitude, latitude order
    coords: {
        type: [Number],
        index: '2dsphere'
    },
    openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
    reviews: [reviewSchema]
});

mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

***EDIT 1*** (Adding additional Error)

with `mongoose.set('debug', true);` I noticed the following:

```
Mongoose: locations.findOne({ _id: ObjectID("84y54uhfsomeid949") }) {fields: undefined}
```

I'm not using a `findOne` function, so I'm not sure what that's about. My theory is that the materials I'm using to learn how to create a schema and insert test data into the database are old or outdated, and that my document is screwed up. (See above for a sample document)

***EDIT 2*** (Changed document's coords to this:)

```
"coords": [
    -84.132809,
    34.180035
],
```

Comment: "coordinates" field in "coords"  is not defined in schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "controller logic" in my code above was for the `app_api`. In my `app_server` controller, I taking the returned data and rendering a page out. After I changed the format in my documents to what I edited above, here's the before and after of the `app_server/controllers/locations.js`:

**before**

```
/* GET 'Location info' page */
module.exports.locationInfo = function(req, res) {
    var requestOptions, path;
    path = "/api/locations/" + req.params.locationid;
    requestOptions = {
        url : apiOptions.server + path,
        method : "GET",
        json : {}
    };
    request(requestOptions, function(err, response, body) {
        var data = body;
        data.coords = {
            lng : body.coordinates[0],
            lat : body.coordinates[1]
        };
        renderDetailPage(req, res, data);
    });
};
```

**after**

```
/* GET 'Location info' page */
module.exports.locationInfo = function(req, res) {
    var requestOptions, path;
    path = "/api/locations/" + req.params.locationid;
    requestOptions = {
        url : apiOptions.server + path,
        method : "GET",
        json : {}
    };
    request(requestOptions, function(err, response, body) {
        var data = body;
        data.coords = {
            lng : body.coords[0],
            lat : body.coords[1]
        };
        renderDetailPage(req, res, data);
    });
};
```

*and also*

**before (document)**

```
"coords": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        -84.132809,
        34.180035
    ]
},
```

**after (document)**

```
"coords": [
    -84.132809,
    34.180035
],
```